# Color Excel based on cell value in VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, csv, vbscript

I have one VBS which convert my csv to excel.
 Now my CSV there are some characters like "!"
I want to color Yellow on those cell which are having that character after converting to excel.

Sample.CSV :

```
 Name,Location,Phone,Comment1,Comment2
 "ABC","Pune",123,"Expert Value","! Easy"
 "XYZ","Kol",567,"! Expert value",Easy"
```

> Requirement : after converting to Excel, I need E2 and D3 Cell should
>   be as Yellow

MyScript.vbs : which needs two argument to execute

```
cscript C:\Test\MyScript.vbs \\C:\Test\Sample.CSV \\C:\Test\Sample.xlsx
```

Here is the original script

```
'======================================
' Convert CSV to XLS
'
' arg1: source - CSV path\file
' arg2: target - Excel path\file
'======================================

srccsvfile = Wscript.Arguments(0)  
tgtxlsfile = Wscript.Arguments(1)  

'Create Spreadsheet
'Look for an existing Excel instance.
On Error Resume Next ' Turn on the error handling flag
Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
'If not found, create a new instance.
If Err.Number = 429 Then  '> 0
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

objExcel.Visible = false
objExcel.displayalerts=false

'Import CSV into Spreadsheet
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.open(srccsvfile)
Set objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Adjust width of columns
Set objRange = objWorksheet1.UsedRange
objRange.EntireColumn.Autofit()
'This code could be used to AutoFit a select number of  columns
'For intColumns = 1 To 17
'    objExcel.Columns(intColumns).AutoFit()
'Next

'Make Headings Bold
objExcel.Rows(1).Font.Bold = TRUE

'Freeze header row
With objExcel.ActiveWindow
     .SplitColumn = 0
     .SplitRow = 1
End With
objExcel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'Add Data Filters to Heading Row
objExcel.Rows(1).AutoFilter

'set header row gray
objExcel.Rows(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
'-0.249977111117893


'Save Spreadsheet, 51 = Excel 2007-2010 
objWorksheet1.SaveAs tgtxlsfile, 51

'Release Lock on Spreadsheet
objExcel.Quit()
Set objWorksheet1 = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the below 'For' loops in your code. It will search for "!" and color the cell yellow. I have coded this in Notepad++ editor. Hence, you may need a bit of debugging.

```
'set header row gray
    objExcel.Rows(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    '-0.249977111117893

    For intRowCounter = 2 to objWorksheet1.usedRange.Rows.Count 'Skip header row
        For intColumnCounter = 1 to objWorksheet1.usedRange.Columns.Count
            If instr(1, objWorksheet1.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter).Value, "!", 1) > 0 Then
                objWorksheet1.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'Shade of Yellow 27, 44 , 36 also can be used 
            End If
        Next
    Next


    'Save Spreadsheet, 51 = Excel 2007-2010 
    objWorksheet1.SaveAs tgtxlsfile, 51
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this code sample...
which is perfectly working on my requirements.
Just wanted to know if I want to pass more than one search value, what I will here.
i.e. some of my cell values are like NOT, NO, NONE and "!" so all those cell I want to highlight.

Comment: Provide a sample of how the data looks

Comment: see.. I have added one sample output in my post, where in my cell value will be like NOT, NO or ! that cell will be yellow